# Windows Boot Manager 0xc0000225

Tags: windows, hardware-failure, hard-drive-recovery

I tried to start my computer, but it suddenly said:

```
Windows Boot Manager  

Windows failed to start. A recent hardware or software change might be the cause.  
To fix the problem:

  1. Insert your Windows installation disc and restart your computer. 
  2. Choose your language settings, and then click "Next."
  3. Click "repair your computer."

If you don't have this disc, contact your system administrator or computer
manufacturer for assistance. 

  Status: 0xc0000225

  Info: The boot selection failed because a required device is inaccessible.
```

Whenever I try to insert a disc, it doesn't read it, the same error comes up. I tried to press F8 or F11, but it was no use. It doesn't read the disc. How do I get my stuff back?

Comment: Sounds like your computer's bios is not configured to boot from a CD/DVD drive.  Do you know the command to enter your bios and adjust the boot order?  Often times it's `DEL` during boot, sometimes `F1` or `F2` (and you want to spam the key, i.e. hit it repeatedly during the first few seconds of boot).  What computer do you have, we may be able to find the exact keys for you.

Comment: @nerdwaller you should make that in a answer.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your computer's bios is not configured to boot from a CD/DVD drive before the H/SDD. <kbd>F8</kbd> is used to get into safe mode for Windows.

To change your boot order, you need to either:

- Find your "boot selection menu" (for me it is <kbd>F12</kbd> on a thinkpad).

**or**

- Enter your bios, change the first boot option to your optical drive

To enter your bios, on many systems it is <kbd>DEL</kbd> (though laptops is often <kbd>F1</kbd> or <kbd>F2</kbd>).  Most systems, unless you changed it, will have a message saying what key it is during the first parts of boot. (*note: you want to "spam" the key it says (i.e. hit it repeatedly) during the first parts of boot, if you miss bios - shut off and try again*)

Once on your bios:  navigate to "boot" or "advanced" and it is probably in there (it's not standard, so we can't give you an exact location).